# conversion of data in OMOP ontological instances to OMOP relational database

Tags: java, postgresql, rdf

Basically, I am following the approach as mentioned [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5937227/) to transform (or map) the source data available in relation tables to OMOP data model and then store it to OMOP tables.

I used D2RQ tool to get source data from various tables in RDF format and applied N3 rules (for mapping source columns to omop tables'columns) via EYE reasoner and transformed source RDF data to OMOP ontological instances.

Now, I have data (as an instance of OMOP ontology) which need to be stored in OMOP CDM tables which I created in PostgreSQL DB.

So, any guidance on how can I store these data to OMOP CDM tables?

Comment: you said you have the tables in PostgreSQL, so shouldn't you simply fill the tables with your data? Via SQL INSERT queries of course? I mean the OMOP data model is online, and you know the table schema, so you should be able to map the corresponding table/column or not? I'm just asking to understand at which point you're stuck. And at least for me, it sound like what you would have to do in the next step.

Comment: Just a further question, you have the RDF data now, why do you want to write it to a SQL database instead of a triple store which is made for RDF?

Comment: Basically, I want to store the RDF data which contains data values corresponding to OMOP tables and columns.

so where should I map the RDF data to OMOP tables/columns structure? I mean through which tool I can do that?
I do not create the SQL queries manually as there are too many tables and much more data.

Any tool would be better in which we can define the mapping between the rdf data and OMOP tables/columns so that it can read the RDF file and fill the data in OMOP table structure or atleast create the SQL insert queries.

Comment: Answer to you last question, to perform the further analysis using various OHDSI tools, I need the RDF data in SQL database.